# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).code is not a function (Summernote)

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I don't know if it's the same error as many got here:

[jQuery is not a function erreor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109847/jquery-is-not-a-function-error)

[how to fix : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function #2087](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2087)

[jquery: Uncaught TypeError: $(…).error is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721804/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-error-is-not-a-function)

But I'm stuck with it like a gum under my shoe.

Here's the actual error on my Chrome's Developer Tools.

[image: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).code is not a function]

I just wish to update Summernote from an older version which has this @ sign error.

[Cant write @ using AltGr + @ combination or Ctrl + Alt +@Combination #1406](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1406)

But then, with the newer version from 0.8.0, it seems that the $(...).code() function is no longer available. Any knows the change I should bring to make it work?

Comment: From documentation it looks like you need to use the summernote() function instead of .code(): https://summernote.org/getting-started/#basic-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://summernote.org/getting-started/#basic-api):

> destroy and code
>
> After v0.7.0, direct jquery methods, destroy and code were removed for
>   avoiding conflict with other jquery libraries. You can call this
>   methods with summernote api.

The **direct** jQuery code() function has been deprecated and you now have to use the summernote() function:

```
$('#summernote').summernote();
```

Answer (score 5):

simply works in my case when I added `defer`

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js" defer></script>
```

My jquery version is 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call the function differently as stated by their API Docs https://summernote.org/getting-started/#basic-api

`$('#summernote').summernote('code');`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I wanted to use summer note with bootstrap4, I copied the below code from the official documentation but it didn't work, I realized afterwards that I was embedding a newer bootstrap version at the beginning of my page (I was reaching out to some bootstrap files located at the assets), I removed that line and everything went just fine:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-bs4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62644428/10121188

Answer (score 0):

###### 1. Steps

I created this post because the suggestions in other posts didn't work in [Summernote v0.8.18](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/releases/tag/v0.8.18).

1. As stated in the [Summernote documentation](https://summernote.org/getting-started/), the following container is defined in the area where the editor will be rendered:

```html
<div id="summernote">Test Application</div>
<button id="print">Print</button>
```

2. The following script is written to load the summernote editor when the web page is loaded:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#summernote').summernote({ height: 95, codemirror: { theme: 'monakai' }});
});
```

3. The method call used to get the Summetnote editor content has been changed:

```js
$('#print').click(function() {
  /* Get the plain text typed into the editor */
  var plainTextContent = $($("#summernote").summernote("code")).text();
  console.log(plainTextContent);
  
  /* Get the formatted text written to the editor */
  var formattedTextContent = $("#summernote").summernote("code");
  console.log(formattedTextContent );
});
```

###### 2. Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#summernote').summernote({ height: 95, codemirror: { theme: 'monakai' } });
});

$('#print').click(function() {
  /* Get the plain text typed into the editor */
  var plainTextContent = $($("#summernote").summernote("code")).text();
  console.log(plainTextContent);
  
  /* Get the formatted text written to the editor */
  var formattedTextContent = $("#summernote").summernote("code");
  console.log(formattedTextContent );
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>

<div id="summernote">
    Test Application
</div>

<button id="print">Print</button>
```